# How to get started with Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have basic php with oops and mvc knowledge. I want to move on Zend Framework so I am wondering that If I want to learn a zend framework than is there any complete application designed on it with project documentation and api documentation?

Comment: Please consider Zend framework 1 and Zend Framework 2 are totally differents

Comment: Hi Vallabh. Please don't interpret the upvote someone has made as meaning that broad, discursive questions are on-topic here. I think this will close, either as "too broad" or "request for third-party resources".

Comment: There are a lot of questions/answers about this topics. (one of manny) http://stackoverflow.com/a/18288420/949273

Answer (score 1):

There is a step by step guide, on their website:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/overview.html

It is the one I followed to get started, and it will give you some basics to begin an application, and then for every specific issue you have just search for them here or on any search engine.

I also bought this book:

[Learn ZF2: Learning By Example](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Learn-ZF2-Learning-Slavey-Karadzhov/dp/1492372218)

Which gave me some more advanced knowledge.

Comment: i find some useful book name called Web Development with Zend framework 2 by Michael Romer